# Installing Scikit-learn extension from GitHub

Tags: python, github, scikit-learn

I use Spyder in Anaconda (on Windows 10) and I'm totally at a loss for how to install this extension of scikit-learn: https://github.com/ivannz/scikit-learn/tree/svdd_l1 . I've tried `pip install git+https://github.com/ivannz/scikit-learn.git` in conda prompt but I got a wheel build error. I need this specific package not the generic scikit-learn because this one has the added functionality I require. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the specific error? It's possible you don't have a compiler installed. Scikit-learn includes C++ code, which will need to be compiled.

Comment: @jakub This is (part of) the error message i get: `Building wheel for scikit-learn (PEP 517) ... error`... `No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils` ...

Comment: Follow scikit-learn's [instructions on building from source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#building-from-source).

Comment: @jakub I think I have now zeroed in on the error. The error is in building the scikit-learn. When I run `python setup.py install` I get the error `distutils.errors.CompileError: Command "cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT /Tctest_program.c /Foobjects\test_program.obj" failed with exit status 127`